# How to load a pre-trained Word2vec MODEL File?

Tags: python, model, word2vec

I'm going to use a pre-trained `word2vec` model, but I don't know how to load it in python.

This file is a MODEL file (703 MB).
http://devmount.github.io/GermanWordEmbeddings/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a pre-trained Word2vec MODEL File and reuse it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549248/how-to-load-a-pre-trained-word2vec-model-file-and-reuse-it)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gensim` like this:

```
import gensim

# Load pre-trained Word2Vec model.
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load("filename.model")
```

More info [here](http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/12/googles-pretrained-word2vec-model-in-python/)

Comment: Thank you @Pravesh, The problem is that this file prefix is ".model" not ".bin"

Comment: No issue, change .bin to . model

Comment: I got this error: _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '6'.

Comment: Raise a new question if there is some another issue.