# How to use deepset's word embedding pre-trained models using gensim?

Tags: python, machine-learning, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I was trying to understand the word2vec and I've decided to give it a go with a German word2vec model. Then I found [deepset's page](https://deepset.ai/german-word-embeddings) about their pre-trained models but I didn't understand how to use (load) word2vec model. I was expecting a single file but there are "[Vectors](https://int-emb-word2vec-de-wiki.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/vectors.txt)" and "[Vocab](https://int-emb-word2vec-de-wiki.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/vocab.txt)" text files. How can I use these files to load a pre-trained model using gensim (or any other tool)?

**UPDATE**:
I've tried the answer of @gojomo and I received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bugra/word2vec_imp/pretrained_models/testtt.py", line 11, in <module>
    binary=False)
  File "/home/bugra/word2vec_imp/project_envv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 1549, in load_word2vec_format
    limit=limit, datatype=datatype)
  File "/home/bugra/word2vec_imp/project_envv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py", line 277, in _load_word2vec_format
    vocab_size, vector_size = (int(x) for x in header.split())  # throws for invalid file format
  File "/home/bugra/word2vec_imp/project_envv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py", line 277, in <genexpr>
    vocab_size, vector_size = (int(x) for x in header.split())  # throws for invalid file format
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "b'UNK'"
```

So, in the Traceack, `vocab_size, vector_size = (int(x) for x in header.split())` the `header` is the first line of the Vector's text from the gensim's page. And it looks like this:

```
b'UNK' -0.07903 0.01641 0.006979 -0.035038 0.006474 0.002469 -0.050103 0.142654 -0.03505 0.003106 -0.021312 0.094076 -0.018255 -0.098097 0.087143 0.105799 0.008606 -0.001315 0.069005 0.062015 0.019944 -0.007749 -0.007412 0.050015 -0.083615 0.007712 0.033161 0.017965 -0.06154 -0.017696 0.061967 0.053028 0.038143 -0.07057 0.01561 0.019588 -0.041708 0.034371 -0.066838 -0.059769 0.075711 -0.114826 0.014009 0.050187 -0.01899 -0.076014 -0.052502 0.086082 0.049812 0.008456 -0.01283 0.039918 -0.001924 -0.003752 0.031073 0.034325 0.040086 0.078946 -0.012194 0.056323 0.126129 -0.024503 0.026304 -0.074797 -0.098972 0.003672 0.051386 -0.017574 -0.050253 -0.07677 0.004362 -0.069935 -0.048108 0.020127 0.007066 -0.024247 0.041911 0.03377 -0.011906 -0.0168 -0.00355 -0.003168 0.05164 -0.055769 0.01488 -6e-06 0.094575 -0.066246 -0.111004 -0.031954 0.006958 0.005259 0.15825 0.102919 0.010383 -0.064236 -0.037729 -0.031751 -0.069492 -0.004198 -0.034654 -0.060518 -0.046611 -0.048463 -0.010096 -0.057894 -0.046687 0.062827 0.016907 0.096869 -0.036037 -0.106403 0.056466 0.095621 -0.046383 0.090213 -0.019204 -0.116271 -0.00824 -0.017732 0.037387 -0.021405 -0.040493 -0.059114 0.12289 0.032563 0.103712 0.072411 -0.106944 -0.110485 -0.027564 0.023977 -0.048099 0.036966 -0.11356 -0.009166 0.074402 0.128162 0.080086 0.112749 0.050494 0.064998 0.089217 0.029182 -0.07277 0.058653 0.061047 -0.05293 -0.01979 0.107459 0.002719 -0.008774 -0.098009 0.009321 0.099869 0.024181 -0.071247 -0.054372 0.019997 0.024442 0.108639 0.053727 -0.089804 0.118491 -0.044407 -0.045336 0.078483 0.059462 -0.012287 0.028941 0.064551 0.066738 0.029614 0.092768 0.021783 -0.018141 -0.032692 0.000178 0.021413 0.044657 -0.041903 0.027439 -0.029112 -0.027419 -0.091497 0.00712 -0.076297 -0.097602 -0.098875 -0.067403 -0.015912 0.055845 0.057585 -0.061145 -0.006828 0.044573 0.049632 0.014541 -0.024579 -0.045455 0.095474 -0.02978 -0.060053 -0.005672 -0.002711 0.059481 -0.060563 0.047562 -0.086001 0.064536 0.196527 -0.105742 -0.019043 0.038534 -0.099681 0.031009 -0.020548 -0.058781 0.064247 0.008213 0.126322 0.029859 0.013129 -0.021303 0.043993 0.033347 0.020245 0.037738 -0.02178 0.027693 -0.07024 0.004687 0.045271 -0.022966 0.014069 0.022861 -0.02787 0.082912 -0.049544 0.016079 -0.004684 0.000572 0.077382 0.036401 0.054974 -0.039538 0.002119 0.034002 -0.008836 -0.014758 0.00959 -0.064647 -0.034766 0.016912 -0.036381 -0.037106 0.073451 -0.098941 -0.092281 -0.018656 0.050538 0.041422 0.041235 0.011248 -0.106058 0.066443 0.083865 0.094636 0.004414 -0.092855 -0.027255 0.005234 0.066584 0.055394 0.023019 -0.001949 -0.066794 -0.064739 0.038924 -0.016647 0.000555 0.02428 0.016469 -0.0467 -0.035343 -0.066789 -0.025929 -0.023397 0.062855 0.020142 -0.047568 0.010299 -0.021509 -0.02826 0.029225 0.01803 0.024336 0.018226 -0.009453 -0.068584
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In Gensim, starting from a properly-formatted plain-text file of vectors with associated `vocab.txt`, you could try:

```py
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

vecs = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('vectors.txt', fvocab='vocab.txt', binary=False)
```

However, per followup discussion below, it appears those files from Deepset **aren't** currently properly-formatted.

Those should be fixed by Deepset, or you should look to some other source for properly-formatted word-vector files, such as [Facebook's Wikipedia-trained vectors for many languages](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/pretrained-vectors.html).)

Comment: I've tried this @gojomo but got an error. Could you please look into the "UPDATE"  title of my question?

Comment: Btw. can I use the `vecs` like it is a regular model? What is `vecs`?

Comment: Those Deepset files for word2vec are improperly-formatted in at least two ways: (1) the format used/read by the original `word2vec.c` tool requires a 1st line that declares the number of vectors & declared dimensionality of each vector; (2) the individual word-tokens should just be whitespace-ended strings, **not** Python binary-string literals. (That is, the 1st line with a vector should begin `UNK ` not `b'UNK' `.) You may wish to contact them & request they fix their formatting if they want their vectors to be easily-usable to outsiders.

Comment: If you just need vectors trained off a German Wikipedia, Facebook has provided them in FastText formats at: <https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/pretrained-vectors.html>. The `.bin` files could be loaded into Gensim's `FastText` class, while the `.vec` files there are just vectors (no FastText character n-grams)  in text format. If you look at those files, you can see the header line & properly-delimited word-tokens that DeepSet's files lack. (I'm not sure what your question about `vecs` was referring-to, as there's no `vecs` things mentioned in your prior question/comment.)

Answer (score 1):

That are the output of a word2vect model, not the trained model

They have shared the code for train the embedding in three different github repositories. They work with docker on AWS instances (EC2) to make the training

https://gitlab.com/deepset-ai/open-source/word2vec-embeddings-de

From the repositories, these are the steps:

> - Download latest articles from german wiki
> - Convert them with gensim into text, single words seperated by space, without punctuation
> - Train word2vec and save the resulting embedding files in the mounted OUTPUTDIR

They use docker to run the models.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `gensim` than below recipe may help you.

https://github.com/devmount/GermanWordEmbeddings

You can simply download the latest wiki base data. If you want to clean it and need help, comment below. I will provide you the detailed steps for that too.

in addition, below is the link which is helpful

[https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html](https://gensim_load_model_or_train)

Comment: Thanks for sharing - is there an easy way to load the pre-trained model?  None of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549248/how-to-load-a-pre-trained-word2vec-model-file-and-reuse-it) worked. ```model = Word2Vec.load("German.model")``` throws UnpcklingError invalid key 6 error that [isn't straight forward to fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049688/what-causes-the-error-pickle-unpicklingerror-invalid-load-key)

Comment: I have added the link above. Try that to load the models word2vec.

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime I managed to download the model from GitHub and load it with gensim. I think I got the wrong model initially.